# particular query not running in php on Godaddy hosting

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run Insert query on my php page but its not executing and takes me to else part.
I have checked query on MySQL its fine. Also I have couple of select queries on the  same page, and those works fine. So I am sure there is no issue with the connection or accessing DB. Heres my code:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 include './db_config.php';

 if ((!isset($_SESSION['first_name']) == true)) {
unset($_SESSION['first_name']);
} 
$logged = $_SESSION['first_name'];

 if ((!isset($_SESSION['id']) == true)) {
unset($_SESSION['id']);
} 
$id = $_SESSION['id']; 

if ((!isset($_SESSION['email']) == true)) {
unset($_SESSION['email']);
}
$email= $_SESSION['email'];  


$query1 = "select * from user_master where id='$id'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
$num1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
if ($num1 > 0) {
  while ($data = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $branch_name = $data['branch_name'];

 } 
}
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
$cust_id=$_POST['cust_id']; 
$meter_no=$_POST['meter_no'];
$lock_no=$_POST['lock_no'];
$customer_name=$_POST['customer_name'];
$customer_type=$_POST['customer_type'];
$customer_zone=$_POST['customer_zone'];
$status=$_POST['status'];
$phoneno=$_POST['phoneno'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$houseno=$_POST['houseno'];
$ownership=$_POST['ownership'];
$landmark=$_POST['landmark'];
$opening_reading=$_POST['opening_reading'];
$opening_reading_date=$_POST['opening_reading_date'];
$branch_name=$_POST['branch_name'];
$created_on=$_POST['created_on'];
$created_by=$_POST['created_by'];
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$consumption=0;
$current_reading=$opening_reading;
$status1="True";
$total_bill=0;
$total_paid=0;
$total_dues=0;

$select="insert into meter(cust_id,meter_no,lock_no,customer_name,customer_type,customer_zone,status,phoneno,city,address,houseno,ownership,landmark,opening_reading,opening_reading_date,created_on,branch_name,created_by,email)
 VALUES('$cust_id','$meter_no','$lock_no','$customer_name','$customer_type','$customer_zone','$status','$phoneno','$city','$address','$houseno','$ownership','$landmark','$opening_reading','$opening_reading_date','$created_on','$branch_name','$created_by','$email')";
            if ($r = mysqli_query($con, $select)) {
            else {
                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo 'alert("Information Not Inserted!!!");';
                //echo 'window.location.href="bill_generation.php";';
                echo '</script>';

            }
```

}

I have Checked on Godaddy [HERE](https://in.godaddy.com/help/connecting-to-mysql-using-php-216) that one need just Localhost as host name.
I know I have pasted a long piece of code, however dont know where the issue is.

Comment: Okay first things first then, do other queries execute, or is this your only query so far? Have you checked your query in a phpmyadmin environment?

Comment: I have select queries to populate customer names in dropdown, works fine. Yes I have checked in MySQL too , it inserts.

Comment: try instead  `if(mysqli_query($con, $select)) {` instead of checking if it is in the `$r` variable.

Comment: ok, however this query runs on local machine

Comment: Also, i am not sure, but i believe the space between your if and your opening statement `()` of the if may be a problem too

Comment: Tried `if(mysqli_query($con, $select)) {` didnt worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180730/discussion-between-mark-and-dorvalla).

Comment: Try look for typos. Online webhosts can be very strict and might be case-sensitive, where localhost environments are very forgiving and not case-sensitive. Make sure everything is spelled correctly in terms of your query etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo at the end of your code.

```
if ($r = mysqli_query($con, $select)) {
    echo 'data inserted successfully !';
    // do something ?
} // this one is missing 
else {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Information Not Inserted!!!");';
    //echo 'window.location.href="bill_generation.php";';
    echo '</script>';

}
```

Comment: I have few lines of code from the code I have shared so it might be deleted. However this page works perfectly in local machine